# Can I get elasticX(), elasticY() to only apply to upper bound, dc.js?

Tags: javascript, d3.js, dc.js, crossfilter

I have a `bubbleChart` in dc.js which has a count on the x-axis. The count cannot be negative, but the upper bound is unknown. I would like my x-axis to always start at 0, but automatically adjust the upper bound to the range I am looking at. If I use `.elasticX(true)`, the upper bound is adjusted automatically as I want it to be, but the lower bound also moves up, see below. Is there an easy way to have the upper bound be elastic, but the lower bound to start at 0?

[image]

Comment: Did you try using `chart.x(d3.scale.<something>().domain( [ 0, Infinity ] ) )` which selects the x-axis ranging from 0 to Infinity?

Comment: This causes all the points to be sitting right on the y axis. Seemingly it does set the max x axis value to 'Infinity' (or some very large number).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It would be great to support this directly; right now there is nothing built in to support this.

However it looks like you can override `xAxisMin` and `yAxisMin` to force them to zero. Something like:

```
chart.xAxisMin = function() { return 0; };
chart.yAxisMin = function() { return 0; };
```

Please let me know if this works for you. It really should be an option in the charts.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I tested this for bubbleChart and seriesChart for both the x and y axes and your solution worked in all 4 cases.

Comment: Thanks for confirming. I've added an issue for this: https://github.com/dc-js/dc.js/issues/924